# xcode 6 App Crash

Tags: ios, xcode

I've been having a problem with my app in Xcode where it crashes. This happens on a variety of iPhones and iOS versions. It highlights this line in the threads
0x4ebf69a:  jae    0x4ebf6aa                 ; __pthread_kill + 26
Can someone please tell me what this line means? I didn't make the app in Xcode so I clueless as to how to go about this. Thanks

Comment: nope, no one will be able to tell you anything with that few info. what else is in the output? do you have a guess why it may crash? was there a point you remember after which it started crashing?

Answer (score 0):

In Xcode, there's there's a crash log that will print in the console. When seeking assistance on this site, posting that log will give other users a chance to look at your problem.

Typically, you'll want to look at what method you've written is causing the crash, which will be noted in the log. You'll want to find that method in your code and put a breakpoint in.

Given the lack of specifics re: your problem, I'd suggest watching this video and circle back with a more detailed question.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7NUQ7LutQlM